# birthday problem via simulation

Tags: sampling, simulation

I would like to plot the cumulative density function for this problem by running the following experiment $p$ times:

generate random numbers between 1 and $n$ and stop when I get a repeat. The x axis will be the number of trials it took.

How do I compute the y axis?

Comment: You state you want a cdf. You're doing simulation, so it's a sample (i.e. empirical) cdf. What's the definition of the [empirical cdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function#Definition)?

Comment: Yes it is an empirical cdf where the y axis is the percent of successes after the number k of trials (i.e. the number of birthday repeats). But how do I compute these for each $k$?

Comment: See the definition in the link; translating that formulat to the present circumstances "the number of elements in the sample $\leq k$, divided by $p$" (the number of simulations)

Comment: Understood. But how do I compute that in practice? I imagine that I have a loop that goes p times and each time through the loop I compute the value of $k$ as described above (I can get any $k$ each $p$ time). $k$ is the number of trials until I get a repeat. How can I use this logic to find the number of elements in the sample $\leq k$? Or I need a different logic for this part?

Comment: Ok I think I got it: I just have to keep tallies of how many trials took less then or equal to $k$ times

Comment: Yes, that's it. Would you like to construct an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

OP didn't take the invitation to give the answer. In order that this have *some* answer I have converted comments to answer:

You want a cdf. You're doing simulation, so it's a sample or [empirical cdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function#Definition); it will be "the number of elements in the sample that are $\leq k$, divided by $p$" (the total number of simulations).

That is, you keep a tally of how many trials took less then or equal to $k$
times and then divide by the total number of trials.